# Is it possible to provide a default value for a generic function's parameter?

Tags: swift

I have a function that prints the `id` of whatever it's passed. One of the parameters it takes is a `KeyPath` to the `id` field since not all entities will have an id field actually called `id`.  What I'd like to do is have the KeyPath parameter have a default value of `\.id` so the caller only has to provide the path to the id property if it differs from the default.

I have this in a playground and it works:

```
import Cocoa

struct StructWithId {
    let id = UUID()
}

func printId<T, idType> (thingWithId: T, idField: KeyPath<T, idType>) {
    print(thingWithId[keyPath: idField])
}

let idThing1 = StructWithId()

printId(thingWithId: idThing1, idField: \.id)
```

However, if I change the function signature to have a default value for the KeyPath parameter like this:

```
func printId<T, idType> (thingWithId: T, idField: KeyPath<T, idType> = \.id) {
    print(thingWithId[keyPath: idField])
}
```

The compiler complains: `Cannot use default expression for inference of 'KeyPath<T, idType>' because it is inferrable from parameters #0, #1`

How do I provide the default value?

Comment: How about just having two functions, one that takes one parameter and the other that takes two paramters?

Comment: Why do you even need this function or is it a simplified version you are showing? I mean why not just do `print(object.idPropertyName)`?

Comment: @Jessy It's added by default when you create a playground.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is just a simplified example to illustrate the concept. It would actually be used in a generic persistence layer that works with CoreData.

Comment: @Jessy I can confirm that selecting the Blank template on the macOS tab in the "Choose a template for your new playground:" window results in the `import Cocoa` line being added by Xcode, along with the subsequent line `var greeting = "Hello, playground"`. This is in Xcode 14.3. Lastly, it is not clear to me what requires fixing. Can you clarify?

Comment: If this is for a generic persistence layer then maybe there is some existing protocol you could make use of and for instance add a `id` property to it, that would simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments that specify the type of one generic placeholder, when that placeholder is used elsewhere in a parameter list, will not compile. (This is not special for key paths.)

```swift
func generic<T>(
  t0: T,
  t1: T = () // Cannot use default expression for inference of 'T' because it is inferrable from parameters #0, #1
) { }
```

Instead, you will either need

1. Explicit overloads:

```swift
func printID<Identifiable, ID>(
  identifiable: Identifiable,
  id: (Identifiable) -> ID
) {
  print(id(identifiable))
}

func printID<Identifiable: Swift.Identifiable>(
  identifiable: Identifiable
) {
  print(identifiable.id)
}
```

2. To switch to an existential:

```swift
func printID<Identifiable: Swift.Identifiable, ID>(
  identifiable: Identifiable,
  id: (any Swift.Identifiable) -> ID = \.id
) {
  print(id(identifiable))
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I said too. :)